# Minimum fixed monthly payment code is not working - infinite loop?

Tags: r, while-loop, infinite-loop

I was taking a course on Phyton but I have found myself using R way more and I tried to solve the problem of calculating the minimuy fixed monthly payment for a given amount. I have the following code that I tried to run in R:

```
balance = 4000
initBalance = balance
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12
month = 0
minPay = 10

calc <- function(month, balance, minPay, monthlyInterestRate) {
  while (month < 12) {
    unpaidBalance = balance - minPay
    balance = unpaidBalance + (monthlyInterestRate * unpaidBalance)
    month = month + 1
    print(balance)
  }
}

while(balance > 0) {
  balance = initBalance
  minPay = minPay + 10
  month = 0
  calc(month = month, balance = balance, minPay = minPay, monthlyInterestRate = 0.2/12)
  print(minPay)
}
```

but when I run it it goes into an infinite loop. What am I missing? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are not updating `balance` in the second loop. It never becomes `<= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
balance = 4000
initBalance = balance
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12
month = 0
minPay = 10

calc <- function(month, balance, minPay, monthlyInterestRate) {
  while (month < 12) {
    unpaidBalance = balance - minPay
    balance = unpaidBalance + (monthlyInterestRate * unpaidBalance)
    month = month + 1
    #print(balance)
  }
  return(balance)
}

balance = 4000
initBalance = 4000

while(balance > 0) {
  minPay = minPay + 10
  month = 0
  balance = calc(month = month, balance = initBalance, minPay = minPay, monthlyInterestRate = 0.2/12)
  print(minPay)
}
```

You can use explicit formula (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equated_monthly_installment):

```
P = 4000       # principal
r = 0.2 / 12   # rate p.m.
n = 12         # number of payments

A = P*( (r*(1+r)^n)/((1+r)^n-1))  
print(A)
#[1] 370.538
```

Comment: Hi @emsinko. I was not sure about how to change balance inside the while loop but now I get it.  Thanks.